# Advanced Scheduled Process/Task Manager - Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scheduled-tasks, scriptmanager

Need some advice, I'm after a decent process/task manager for Ubuntu.

Basically I have a few scripts/programs which I want to run as long running processes, but I want to shut them down at various periods (say over the weekend or every day for a few hours). During the time that the process needs to be up and crashes, I would like it so that the task scheduler will automatically restart the process.

SO for example, I want to run program X between 9:00-17:00 every day. If the process is still running it should be killed at 17:00. If the process crashes between 9AM and 5PM then the process should be automatically restarted.

Are there any easy to use tools which can do this? I would like to avoid having to manage PID files and having cron jobs which do the start and stop...

Any thing anyone recommends? Any advice appreciated!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if a tool exists for this, but except if you have many interactive tasks, it really does not a that big issue to manage for a few jobs :

1) You can start your cronjobs whenever you like thanks to the crontab,

2) You can insert a "commit suicide" within these scripts under a time condition for example.

```
# your script doing things
# Then it commit suicide
if [ your_condition ];then
  kill $$
fi
```

Please note that if you want to allow users login only at certain periods of time, then it's a different question.

Comment: Yeah not really what I'm after sounds like it would be easier to write a wrapper script which handles this...